# How can I pick and rename certain keys using TypeScript, while maintaining JSDoc comments?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, jsdoc

How can I pick and rename certain keys from another type, while keeping the JSDoc comments and the "property link"? *("property link" see below)*

Let there be 2 base interfaces.

```
interface BoxProps {
  /** Some elaborate description */
  className: string
}

interface LayoutProps {
  /** Different elaborate description */
  className: string
}
```

Now I want to combine them in one interface, but I am losing the valuable JSDoc comments.

```
interface ChildProps extends BoxProps {
  outerClassName: LayoutProps['className']
}

declare const x: ChildProps
```

Which results in following.

1. `className` is recognized as linked to `BoxProps.className` with original JSDoc.
2. `outerClassName` is obviously from `ChildProps`, but desired would be `LayoutProps.className`. **JSDoc is "lost"** (not inlined from the JSDoc of the type annotation to the "renamed" field).

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know (though I'd be very happy to be shown to be wrong), this is not possible.

There's a related JSDoc annotation called [`inheritdoc`](https://jsdoc.app/tags-inheritdoc.html), but that's not applicable here due to the "renaming".

I think the best you can get is to use `@see` (which VS Code supports through tsserver (see TypeScript's [4.1 release notes](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#editor-support-for-the-jsdoc-see-tag))), like so:

```
interface ChildProps extends BoxProps {
   /**@see {LayoutProps#className} */
   outerClassName: LayoutProps['className']
}
```

, which doesn't give inline hover info, but at the very least you can "Go To Definition" on usages of the method, which will take you to where you can then "Go To Definition" on the `className` method in that `@see` annotation. Hopefully someday the builtin TypeScript extension will get an upgrade so that it will also create a clickable link in the [hover info](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#Hover) for the @see annotation.