# Function will understand typing, but won't show JSDoc comments

Tags: typescript

I have the following code:

```
interface thisfile {
    /**
     * A test function to demonstrate this issue
     */
    testFunction: () => string     // 1
}

const testFunction: thisfile['testFunction'] = () => {   // 2
    return 'hello'
}

export default {
    testFunction   // 3
} as thisfile
```

In this code, the type for `testFunction` is defined inside of the interface `thisfile`. The corresponding JSDoc will show up when hovering over the function at **// 1** and **// 3**, but not **// 2**. However, if I made a mistake in the typing, like changing `() => string` to `() => number`, it'll throw an error at **// 2**.

This tells me that the the type is correctly acquired from the `testFunction` property of the `thisfile` interface, but it just isn't showing the JSDoc for some reason.

What am I missing here? Seems odd

Comment: check this one out, it might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75861806/how-can-i-pick-and-rename-certain-keys-using-typescript-while-maintaining-jsdoc

Comment: @v0rs4 I couldn't really figure much out from that. Correct me if I'm wrong, still wrapping my head around TS, but I don't understand the issue they're having either. 
I'm confused as to why a function cannot inherit JSDocs when it's type is a property of an interface, but it can inherit the type definition. Is there really no way to keep the JSDocs in one place here?

Answer (score 2):

*can't leave a comment, 50 reputation required*

Apparently there's no way to keep the JSDocs in one place. I have tried numerous things and none of them yielded desired outcome.

Comment: Yup, I'm not finding anything either. Quite unfortunate bug.